# Clear browser network requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to clear all the logs of network requests that shows in browser debugger tool network section.

Comment: You mean, with JavaScript code running in the page? Pretty sure you can't, at least not cross-browser.

Comment: I am curious, why?

Comment: I don't want to allow users to see requests flow on network.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have seen some banking sites doing the same.

Comment: @SachinRajput: I suspect that's observation error. For instance, many consoles clear the network panel when you refresh the page.